# No se muestran todas las imágenes en el front de mi proyecto Spring Boot

Tags: html, spring-boot, imagen, thymeleaf, enlace

estoy teniendo unos problemas con mi proyecto realizado con Spring Boot, precisamente con el front.

Se trata de una peluquería canina donde se pueden ingresar mascotas, dueños y consultar la base de datos.

El problema está en el footer del front, estoy usando una plantilla de Bootstrap. De la forma que muestro a continuacion, linkeando los íconos con Thymeleaf, funciona perfecto en el index.

```
 <ul class="nav col-md-4 justify-content-end list-unstyled d-flex">


            
                <li class="ms-3">
                    <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/esteban-cardozo19/" target="_blank"><img
                            th:src="@{linkedin.svg}" alt="Linkedin" class="text-body-secondary"></a>
                </li>
                <li class="ms-3">
                    <a href="https://github.com/EstebanCardoz0" target="_blank"><img th:src="@{github.svg}" alt="Github"
                            class="text-body-secondary"></a>
                </li>
                <li class="ms-3">
                    <a href="mailto:esteban.cardozo.wec@gmail.com" target="_blank"><img th:src="@{envelope-at-fill.svg}"
                            alt="Mail" class="text-body-secondary"></a>
                </li>


            </ul>
```

[image: Así se ve en el Index]

Ahora bien, utilizando EL MISMO código para el footer de las otras páginas (alta de mascota, dueño, listas, etc) no se ven los íconos:

[image: Así en las demás páginas]

Probé usando de la manera tradicional sin Thymeleaf y sigue sin funcionar. Saben qué podría ser? Desde ya gracias